# Spring Autowired in Web Service not working

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, autowired

I must be missing something simple, but I'm having trouble getting an Autowired property to be assigned to a bean.  All similar answers posted here seem to revolve around one of three solutions:

1. extend SpringBeanAutowiringSupport
2. use <context:component-scan base-package="..." /> in applicationContext.xml
3. use <context:annotation-config /> in applicationContext.xml

I tried to make a minimalist bean to represent my DAO and inject it into a Web Service.

DAO interface:

```
package wb;
public interface FooDAO {
    public String doNothing();
}
```

DAO implementation:

```
package wb;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class FooDAOImpl implements FooDAO {
    public FooDAOImpl() {
        System.out.println("FooDAOImpl: Instantiated " + this);
    }

    @Override
    public String doNothing() {
        System.out.println("FooDAOImpl: doNothing() called");
        return "Did nothing!";
    }
}
```

Web Service with injection:

```
package ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;
import wb.FooDAO;

@WebService(serviceName = "WS")
public class WS extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private FooDAO fooDAO;

    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public void setFooDAO(FooDAO fooDAO) {
        this.fooDAO = fooDAO;
        System.out.println("WS: fooDAO set = " + fooDAO);
    }

    public WS() {
        System.out.println("WS: WS bean instantiated!");
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "doNothing")
    @WebResult(name = "whatDidIDo")
    public String doNothing() {
        System.out.println("WS: doNothing() says DAO = " + fooDAO);
        return fooDAO == null ? "Could not do nothing!" : fooDAO.doNothing();
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml content within the beans tags:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="ws"/>

<bean id="fooDAO" class="wb.FooDAOImpl" />
```

This was all created in the latest NetBeans, in a project created with Spring and Hibernate frameworks.  When I deploy to JBoss, and the app starts up, I get the expected Bean instantiation:

```
11:01:46,767 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-6) WS: WS bean instantiated!
11:01:47,571 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-15) FooDAOImpl: Instantiated wb.FooDAOImpl@11176682
```

Once I call the web service, the log also reports:

```
11:03:07,097 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) WS: doNothing() says DAO = null
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` must be a bean. You need to annotate that class with `@Service` or another annotation such as `@Component` that indicates a class should be a bean when component scanning occurs.  These will be picked up by `Spring` and made into beans.

Remember that in order to be a participant in autowiring, such as having another bean injected, the class must be a bean itself and managed by Spring's IOC container.

Comment: Thanks; could have sworn that's one of the things I'd tried previously.  When I add @Component, it works.

Comment: @user3207820 Glad I could help.  I struggled with some the same concepts early on when using Spring.  Anytime you use the `new` keyword you really need to pause and wonder if its appropriate.

Comment: The WS instance created during App startup gets an auto-wired DAOImpl.  But when calling the web service, a different WS instance is created to field the requests, and THAT instance doesn't get one.  Weird.  Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same exact thing as the above comment. I can't get the instance created when calling the web service to have the autowired fields. Am I doing something wrong with how I'm creating the web service? Or did I not follow the solution correctly? Spring is definitely creating the WS class as a bean, but it's not the same instance used when calling the service.

Answer (score 0):

The `spring` should start before `webservices`.

The the `webservices-rt*.jar` is a plugable jar which starts automaticly to find the end points.

In some cases it may happen that the webservices starts before spring. So the `injects` can not be done. Make sure that the start up has correct order.