# Java null pointer exception @autowired in web service

Tags: java, spring, oracle, nullpointerexception, jdeveloper

ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException at domain.SpeakerRecog.test

speakermapper is null, error is on `speakermapper.insertUserAndEnrollmentId(userid, enrollmentid)` it throws Java null pointer exception. Datasource was created in console. I tried adding annotations like `@Configuration`, `implements`, it still wont work. I am trying to insert data into table of a database in localhost. Its different from the thread "Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?" since i did not create a new constructor, but i followed the suggestion given there but it still wont work

**WebService java file:**

```
package domain;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import mapper.Speakermapper;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@WebService(serviceName = "SpeakerRecognitionWS")

public class SpeakerRecog extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport{


    @Autowired
    private Speakermapper speakermapper;


    @WebMethod
    public String test(){


        String userid = "111";
        String enrollmentid = "111";
        try{ 
        speakermapper.insertUserAndEnrollmentId(userid, enrollmentid);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}
```

**Here is Speakermapper.java file:**

```
package mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

public interface Speakermapper {
    public void insertUserAndEnrollmentId(@Param("userid") String userid, 
                            @Param("enrollmentid") String enrollmentid);

}
```

**Here is Speakermapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace = "mapper.Speakermapper">
<insert id = "insertUserAndEnrollmentId" >
Insert into SpeakerIds 
(userid, enrollmentid)
Values (#{userid}, #{enrollmentid})
</insert>
</mapper>
```

**Here is applicationContext.xml: Is there error on this xml. I cant figure it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
        <context:component-scan base-package="domain"/> 
        <context:component-scan base-package="mapper"/> 
        <bean id="SpeakerRecog"  class="domain.SpeakerRecog" />
        <bean id="smapper"  class="mapper.speakermapper" />

        <bean id="dataSourceSpeaker" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="Speaker"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="sqlSessionFactorySpeaker" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSpeaker"/>
            <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="domain"/>
            <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="mapperSpeaker" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
            <property name="basePackage" value="mapper" />
            <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactorySpeaker" />
        </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Probably your sping environment is not booting up as a result of which the autowiring is not being done.

Comment: how to boot up spring environment? sorry i am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly mark it as a service, or not use an interface but rather a class.

Have looked again ---> maybe this is the problem

```
  <bean id="smapper"  class="mapper.speakermapper" />
```

Speakermapper with big S

```
  <bean id="smapper"  class="mapper.Speakermapper" />
```

```
package mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Speakermapper {
    public void insertUserAndEnrollmentId(@Param("userid") String userid, 
                            @Param("enrollmentid") String enrollmentid);

}
```

Update 3

```
<bean id="speakermapper"  class="mapper.Speakermapper" />
<bean id="SpeakerRecog"  class="domain.SpeakerRecog" >
     <property name="speakermapper" ref="speakermapper" />
</bean>
```

Please also check this link:

[Spring Autowired in Web Service not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193843/spring-autowired-in-web-service-not-working)

Comment: Th example will not even compile.

Comment: It doesn't compile because he didn't import `Service`, it should be fixed now

Comment: @Haris Bouchlis it doesn't compile because a regular class could not provide a method without implementation. And it simply cannot be a class because If you carefully review OP, this is not a regular interface, but a MyBatis interface, so one cannot simply substitute it with a class.

Comment: i already tried @Service but still null pointer exception.

Comment: Can anybody help

Comment: @WilsonChua please look at my updated answer.

Comment: same error. are there jar files i should import for the applicationContext.xml?

Comment: Please try update 3. @WilsonChua

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193843/spring-autowired-in-web-service-not-working

Comment: Thanks for the response. i have tried the 3 solutions given on the link above, but still no luck

Comment: anybody else can help pls

Comment: Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193843/spring-autowired-in-web-service-not-working. Can you please give an upvote to my answer ?